# Disable MySQL's UNION SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

Is it possible to completely disable `UNION SELECT` queries thru a configuration option?

Besides cleaning the entry params, I would like to avoid the use of `UNION` since with its help it is pretty easy to implement `SQL injection` of the form:

```
SELECT * FROM users where username = '1' OR 1=1 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM users -- ' AND password='something'
```

Comment: There are better ways to protect against injection attacks

Comment: Injections at least should be handled properly, not by disabling features and assuming it would do anything to help the situation. As for the actual question, I don’t know of any way to disable parts of the language.

Comment: Googling "Prevent SQL injection" would be the preferred course of action instead.

Comment: Well, i am tired of your preaching! I know how to escape the input params, I know how to use prepared statements. I just wanted to know whether there is a config option to disable `UNION` select queries. That's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question plainly:

No, there is no option in MySQL to selectively disable `UNION`.

SQL_MODE can be used to change the meaning of syntax in a couple of very specific cases, like use of double-quotes and the `||` operator. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html

But in general, you cannot disable SQL keywords or clauses, unless you whip out your code editor and modify MySQL's SQL parser code, and then build a custom instance of MySQL.

I agree with the other commenters that it isn't necessary to disable `UNION` if you write application code with the known practices to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Even it's easy to do SI with plain `SELECT` query as well and it has nothing to do with `UNION` at all. Moreover, as far I know, NO there is no such option to disable `UNION` unless you are probably taken the open source code and modified it yourself.

Comment: Are you sure there is no config option? Maybe I am mistaken. Anyways thanks for actually answering my question :) BTW, I can't think of another way to extract records from a different table with SI but to use UNION.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov yes, pretty much

Answer (score 0):

The best [proven] solution to avoid SQL Injection is to avoid assembling SQL statements by concatenating strings with values coming from the end user interface (or other unsafe source).

It's safer to use "Prepared Statements" and **apply** parameters to it, instead of **concatenating** those parameters.

There's still room for concatenating SQL chunks into a statements, primarily when using Dynamic SQL, but I think this is out of the scope of your question. In simple words: **do not concatenate values as strings when producing a SQL statement**.

Comment: I know how to escape the input params, I know how to use prepared statements. I just wanted to know whether there is a config option to disable UNION select queries. That's it!